# Why does sed globally substitute only the first occurence in multiple substiutions?

Tags: sed, escape-characters, newlines

I want to globally substitute all `\n` new line characters with their `\n` escape sequence and all `'` single quote characters with two `''` of them like so:

```
function esc_foobar {
    # Escapes any "'" single quotation character.
    local -r esc_quot="s:':'':g"
    # Escapes any "\n" new line character.
    local -r esc_nl=':a;N;$!ba;s:\n:\\n:g'
    # Escape everything in one sed run.
    sed -- "$esc_quot;$esc_nl" foobar.txt
}
```

Given that the `foobar.txt` file contains:

```
Foo's bar
Bar's foo
```

Only the first `'` single quote character gets doubled.

Reversing the order of the `esc_quot` and `esc_nl` substitutions in the `sed` command to `$esc_nl;$esc_quot` works, i.e. all `'` single quote characters get doubled as expected.

Why is this so?

Comment: I know to substitute with sed globally you should use s'/foo/bar/g' The s means substitute and g means globally

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect that what is happening is that in the first form, the first line is scanned, the quote mark replaced, then the line is rescanned, and the newline character is replaced. The second line is no longer there to be scanned, because it is now already joined to the first.

In the second form, the first line is scanned, and the new line character is replaced, the line now containing both the first and second line is rescanned and all quotes replaced.

Perhaps someone can confirm or correct my understanding?

Comment: @Warwick: Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

After working myself into Sed and particularly trying to get my head around Sed's `N` command I came up with the following little Sed script that works for me:

```
sed -- '$!N;s:\n:\\n:g;'"s:':'':g"
```

The second variant of the Sed script from my question has the problem that it leaves the last line untouched if the number of lines of input happens to be odd.